# Ivy CleanCache Task throwing NullPointException

Tags: java, ant, ivy, slf4j

I have the following project directory structure:

```
MyProject/
    src/main/java/
        All of my Java sources
    build/
        build.xml
        build.properties
        ivy.xml
        ivy-settings.xml
        ivy-settings.properties
```

The `build.xml` looks like this:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="audit" basedir=".." xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <property file="build/build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>

    <path id="ant.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="${env.ANT_HOME}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ant.lib.path"/>

    <target name="configIvy">
        <echo message="Configuring Ivy."/>
        <echo message="URL is: ${ivy.settings.home}"/>
        <ivy:settings url="${ivy.settings.home}"/>

        <!-- Clear/flush the Ivy cache. -->
        <echo message="Cleaning the local Ivy cache for the current build."/>
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>
</project>
```

When I run `ant -buildfile /<path-to-my-project>/MyProject/build/build.xml configIvy`, I get the following console output:

```
Buildfile: /<path-to-my-project>/MyProject/build/build.xml

configIvy:
    [echo] Configuring Ivy.
    [echo] URL is: file:////<path-to-my-project>/MyProject/build/ivy-settings.xml
[ivy:cleancache] :: Apache Ivy 2.3.0-rc1 - 20120416000235 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::

BUILD FAILED
/<path-to-my-project>/MyProject/build/build.xml:85: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.url.URLHandlerRegistry.getHttp(URLHandlerRegistry.java:47)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyAntSettings.configureURLHandler(IvyAntSettings.java:367)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyAntSettings.createIvyEngine(IvyAntSettings.java:267)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyAntSettings.getConfiguredIvyInstance(IvyAntSettings.java:237)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.getIvyInstance(IvyTask.java:92)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.prepareTask(IvyTask.java:256)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:276)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.isDebugEnabled(Category.java:129)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.isDebugEnabled(Log4JLogger.java:239)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.<clinit>(HttpClient.java:69)
    ... 25 more
```

My `ivy-settings.xml` file specifies a URL resolver of an Artifactory repo that is hosted on my local machine (`http://localhost:8080/artifactory/myrepo`). I'm wondering if Ivy uses HttpClient under the hood (as the stacktrace suggests), and for some reason, is choking because its an HTTP URL on the same machine? Maybe?!? And *yes*, I'm sure that the URL is correct and that Artifactory is running while I run the Ant build!

Can anyone spot what is going on here? Why would `<ivy-cleancache>` throw a NPE? I'm looking at its source code and can't seem to find where the NPE is coming from, or why. I can supply more details if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I see `Log4J` I give up. But looks like the answer is rather in `log4j` source code, thany ivy itself. What is that `Category`?

Comment: Ahhh, starting to get *somewhere* (+1 for the keen eye!). I recently added SLF4J's `log4-over-slf4j.jar` to my ${ANT_HOME}/lib directory for something I was doing with another project. Is it conceivable that there's something in my project (such as Ivy) that is attempting to use Log4J, but since `log4j-over-slf4j` merely mimicks Log4j, it throws a runtime exception?

Comment: You're welcome. I think the question becomes 'too localized' now, you may delete it :)

Comment: I *might* agree on deleting it, but am actively researching this right now. My theory is that Ivy is calling some Apache Commons code, that in turn calls Log4J code, that in turn calls SLF4J code, and an NPE is cropping up somewhere. If this is a "bug" between Ant/Ivy and SLF4J I would probably be in favor of keeping this question alive (its not inconceivable that others might experience it), and subsequently reporting it to the appropriate team.

Comment: UPDATE: I removed `log4j-over-slf4j` from Ant's lib/ directory and - voila - the problem is gone! I'm still researching as to why, because now I've broken my other project :-(.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I gave a response to this, but I don't see it here...

Don't put extra jars for your projects into `$ANT_HOME/lib`. There are several reasons for this:

- As you've found out, there can be jar clash as each set of optional tasks tries to setup the classpath they need. Yes, it's nice not having to set a classpath when you do a `<taskdef>`, but it's not that bad.
- If you give your project to someone else, they'll have to install all of the optional jars too before they can do a build.

The better way is to create a `${basedir}/ant.lib` directory, and then put each set of ant task jars in their own sub-directory. For example, you'd put Ivy jars in `${basedir}/ant.lib/ivy` and you put Checkstyle jars in `${basedir}/ant.lib/checkstyle`. Then, you define your taskdef with a classpath pointing to the directory like this:

```
 <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" 
      uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
      <classpath>
          <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib/ivy"/>
      </classpath>
 </taskdef>
```

This way, Ivy doesn't pick up the wrong jars. As a bonus, you can also give someone your project, and Ivy is already installed and running for them. No need for them to download Ivy and setup the jar in the right classpath.

By the way, `$ANT_HOME/lib` is already in the Ant classpath, so if you didn't specify a classpath, all the jars in `$ANT_HOME/lib` will be picked up automatically. You could have simply done this:

```
 <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" 
      uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant"/>
```

with no classpath required.